# How to create a RegEx for finding the first two words after a comma?

Tags: c#, regex

So the string is:

```
Booked By ........: jhon volta, jack smith bla
```

or

```
Booked By ........: jack, gardiner
```

From the first string, I need to extract "jhon volta" in one group and "jack smith" in another group.

From the second string, I need to extract "jack" in the first group and "gardiner" in the second group.

So basically, I want to extract the name before the comma, and only the two words after the comma. My current RegEx is this:

```
(.*Booked By ........: .*)(\s\S+(?=,))(,[\S]*)
```

This currently extracts the name before the comma, but only the first word after the comma. I need it to extract two words after the comma.

Comment: The OP states ' two words after a comma' -- Not correct. It is two names containing a comma following a colon...

Comment: @dawg What OP said is correct ... his mean `: anything, word1 word2 anything`

Comment: His title does not match the examples

Comment: Yeah .. agreed ..!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :

`(?<=: )(\w+[\s\w]*), (\w+(?:\s\w+){0,1})`

this one gets the name after the `:` and the first two words after the `,`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?<=:\s|,\s)\b\w+\s*\w*\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bZ2eW4/1)

**Explanation:**
`(?<=…)`: Positive lookbehind [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wU2aD6/1)
`\s`: "whitespace character": space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab [sample](https://regex101.com/r/pD4dR7/1)
`|`: Alternation / OR operand [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ0iC0/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`\w`: "word character": ASCII letter, digit or underscore [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ2lG4/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)

Comment: OP wants two separate capturing group for those two names.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

```
/: ([^,]+), (\w+(?: \w+)?)/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dU1qU3/1)

Comment: but when i find Groups[1].Value;, it returns the last letter of the name before the comma instead of the full name. is there a solution to this? For example, I want group 1 to be "john volta" instead of "a" which is currently is giving me.

Comment: What you said is impossible. As you see in [my demo](https://regex101.com/r/dU1qU3/1) all of `john volta` is matched as green-color. So when you get `$1` it will be containing `john volta`. Otherwise, there is a problem in your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
((?:(?:\w+)\s)?\w+,\s\w+(?:\s\w+)?)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oZ0wW4/1)

Or

```
((?:(?:\w+)\s)?\w+),\s*(\w+(?:\s\w+)?)
```

If you want two groups

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/oZ0wW4/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
(?<=:)\s*([^,]+),\s*([^\s]+(?:\s*[^\s]+)?)
```